# Updating GitLab via omnibus-gitlab not update

Tags: gitlab

I tried update [gitlab via omnibus](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update.md).
Stop services not problem:

```
$ sudo gitlab-ctl stop unicorn
timeout: run: unicorn: (pid 12257) 582s, want down, got TERM
$ sudo gitlab-ctl stop sidekiq
ok: down: sidekiq: 0s, normally up
$ sudo gitlab-ctl stop nginx
ok: down: nginx: 1s, normally up
```

Download and install too:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i gitlab_7.9.2-omnibus-1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 99917 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gitlab 7.9.2-omnibus-1 (using gitlab_7.9.2-omnibus-1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gitlab ...
Setting up gitlab (7.9.2-omnibus-1) ...
Thank you for installing GitLab!
Configure and start GitLab by running the following command:

sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure

GitLab should be reachable at http://GitHub.lcl.loc
Otherwise configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
And running reconfigure again.

For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md
```

When reconfigure:

```
$ sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
[sudo] password for git:
the ffi-yajl and yajl-ruby gems have incompatible C libyajl libs and should not be loaded in the same Ruby VM
falling back to ffi which might work (or might not, no promises)
Starting Chef Client, version 11.12.2
Compiling Cookbooks...
Recipe: gitlab::default
  * directory[/etc/gitlab] action create (up to date)
[2015-04-13T02:36:18+03:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/opt/gitlab] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2015-04-13T02:36:18+03:00] WARN: Previous directory[/var/opt/gitlab]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:40:in `from_file'
[2015-04-13T02:36:18+03:00] WARN: Current  directory[/var/opt/gitlab]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/users.rb:23:in `from_file'
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Previous directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-rails.rb:43:in `block in from_file'
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Current  directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/definitions/unicorn_config.rb:21:in `block in from_file'
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for service[unicorn] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Previous service[unicorn]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:78:in `block in from_file'
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Current  service[unicorn]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:191:in `block in from_file'
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for service[sidekiq] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Previous service[sidekiq]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:78:in `block in from_file'
[2015-04-13T02:36:19+03:00] WARN: Current  service[sidekiq]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:191:in `block in from_file'
Converging 191 resources
  * directory[/etc/gitlab] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/embedded/etc] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/gitconfig] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::users
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * group[git] action create (up to date)
  * user[gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::web-server
  * group[gitlab-www] action create (up to date)
  * user[gitlab-www] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-shell
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] action create (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/authorized_keys.lock] action create (up to date)
  * execute[chcon --recursive --type ssh_home_t /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] action run (skipped due to only_if)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/git-data] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/config.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab_shell_secret] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/.gitlab_shell_secret] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/working] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/tmp] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/backups] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/secret] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.secret] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/database.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/database.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/resque.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/resque.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/aws.yml] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/aws.yml] action delete (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/smtp_settings.rb] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb] action delete (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/rack_attack.rb] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/rack_attack.rb] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.gitlab_shell_secret] action create
    - unlink existing file at /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.gitlab_shell_secret
    - create symlink at /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.gitlab_shell_secret to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab_shell_secret

  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/gitlab-satellites] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/HOME] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/RAILS_ENV] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/SIDEKIQ_MEMORY_KILLER_MAX_RSS] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/BUNDLE_GEMFILE] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/PATH] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/tmp] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/uploads] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/log] action create (up to date)
  * link[/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sidekiq.log] action create (skipped due to not_if)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/schema.rb] action create
    - change owner from 'root' to 'gitlab'

  * remote_file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/VERSION] action create (up to date)
  * execute[chown -R root:root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public] action run
    - execute chown -R root:root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: gitlab::cron
  * cron[gitlab-ci schedule builds] action delete (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::default
  * service[unicorn] action nothing (up to date)
  * service[ci-unicorn] action nothing (up to date)
  * service[sidekiq] action nothing (up to date)
  * service[ci-sidekiq] action nothing (up to date)
Recipe: runit::sysvinit
  * execute[echo 'CS:123456:respawn:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start' >> /etc/inittab] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * execute[init q] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: gitlab::redis
  * group[gitlab-redis] action create (up to date)
  * user[gitlab-redis] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/redis] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/redis] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.conf] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/log] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/log/main] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/log/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/log/gitlab/redis/config] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[reload redis svlogd configuration] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/down] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/init/redis] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/redis] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * service[redis] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: gitlab::ci-redis_disable
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/ci-redis] action delete (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::postgresql
  * group[gitlab-psql] action create (up to date)
  * user[gitlab-psql] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/postgresql] action create (up to date)
  * link[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data] action create (skipped due to not_if)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.profile] action create (up to date)
  * service[procps] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * template[/etc/sysctl.d/90-postgresql.conf] action create (up to date)
  * execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/pg_ident.conf] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgresql] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgresql/log] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgresql/log/main] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgresql/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgresql/log/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/log/gitlab/postgresql/config] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[reload postgresql svlogd configuration] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgresql/down] action delete (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgresql/control] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgresql/control/t] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/init/postgresql] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/postgresql] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[supervise_postgresql_sleep] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * service[postgresql] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * execute[create gitlab database user] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * execute[create gitlabhq_production database] action run (skipped due to not_if)
Recipe: gitlab::unicorn
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/unicorn] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/var/unicorn] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/unicorn] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/unicorn/log] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/unicorn/log/main] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/unicorn/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/unicorn/log/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/log/gitlab/unicorn/config] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[reload unicorn svlogd configuration] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/unicorn/down] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/init/unicorn] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/unicorn] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[supervise_unicorn_sleep] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * service[unicorn] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: gitlab::ci-unicorn_disable
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/ci-unicorn] action delete (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::sidekiq
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/sidekiq] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/sidekiq] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/sidekiq/log] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/sidekiq/log/main] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/sidekiq/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/sidekiq/log/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/config] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[reload sidekiq svlogd configuration] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/sidekiq/down] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/init/sidekiq] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[supervise_sidekiq_sleep] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * service[sidekiq] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: gitlab::ci-sidekiq_disable
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/ci-sidekiq] action delete (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::nginx
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/nginx] action create (up to date)
  * link[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/logs] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx.conf] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/nginx] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/nginx/log] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/nginx/log/main] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/nginx/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/nginx/log/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/log/gitlab/nginx/config] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[reload nginx svlogd configuration] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/nginx/down] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/init/nginx] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/nginx] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[supervise_nginx_sleep] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * service[nginx] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: gitlab::remote-syslog_disable
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/remote-syslog] action delete (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::logrotate
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/logrotate] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/logrotate/logrotate.d] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/logrotate] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/logrotate/logrotate.conf] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/logrotate/logrotate.d/nginx] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/logrotate/logrotate.d/unicorn] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/logrotate/logrotate.d/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/logrotate/logrotate.d/gitlab-shell] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/logrotate/logrotate.d/gitlab-ci] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/main] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/log/gitlab/logrotate/config] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[reload logrotate svlogd configuration] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/down] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/init/logrotate] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/logrotate] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[supervise_logrotate_sleep] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * service[logrotate] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: gitlab::database_migrations
  * execute[initialize gitlab-rails database] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * execute[initialize gitlab-ci database] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * bash[migrate gitlab-ci database] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete

Chef Client finished, 3/159 resources updated in 8.010458663 seconds
gitlab Reconfigured!

$ sudo gitlab-ctl restart
ok: run: logrotate: (pid 20218) 1s
ok: run: nginx: (pid 20221) 0s
ok: run: postgresql: (pid 20225) 1s
ok: run: redis: (pid 20227) 0s
ok: run: sidekiq: (pid 20237) 0s
ok: run: unicorn: (pid 20240) 1s
```

Befor and after update:

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:         Debian 7.8
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.1.2p95
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.7.4
Rake Version:   10.4.2
Sidekiq Version:2.17.0

GitLab information
Version:        7.4.2
Revision:       477743a
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            https://GitHub.lcl.loc/gitlab
HTTP Clone URL: https://GitHub.lcl.loc/gitlab/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@GitHub.lcl.loc:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        2.0.1
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

Now Dashboard loading, but where I have look page Projects, issues error 500. Where I have look one project, issues error 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! in my server was worked gitlab service and gitlab-ctl. They are in conflict. Gitlab service starting fast and gitlab-ctl fail. Gitlab service is version 7.4.2. Gitlab-ctl version 7.9.2.

When I updated, I noticed [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update.md#upgrading-from-a-non-omnibus-installation-to-an-omnibus-installation).